# Can I do something so that arguments to superconstructor are passed implicitly?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor

I have a situation where the top class requires a parameter while none of the child classes does. Some class:

```
class SuperClass {
public:
    SuperClass(const int parameter);
}
```

And it's child:

```
class NoParametersInConstructorClass : public SuperClass {
public:
    // This will cause an error:
    // error: no matching function for call to 'SuperClass::SuperClass(const int)'
    NoParametersInConstructorClass() : someText("Hello") {};
private:
    std::string someText
}
```

Now the problem I am facing is that I do have an initializer list, but I find it tedious to rewrite the arguments in all child classes. I am lazy I know. I would like this to work without explicitly defining it:

```
// Works even though NoParametersInConstructorClass(const int) isn't defined
NoParametersInConstructorClass variable(66);
```

Of course, if there is no way, there is no way, but is there?

Comment: Can you show us your actual code? Child class doesn't seem to inherit base class so I'm not sure if I understand your question. You can call the super class constructor explicitly `SuperClass(5)` in the child class if you meant that.

Comment: Assuming your child inherits from base requiring an argument, how do you want to call it's constructor when you are not giving it an argument? Should compiler use random number?

Comment: @JameyD I am sorry, I just forgot to write the `: public SuperClass`. And I am currently using the explicit call. My actual code is pretty much same as the one you're seeing, only the names are `Graph`, `BigGraph` and sevelar similar and the parameter is `GraphData*`. So no need to see any more actual code I guess.

Comment: You can just remove the parameter from your base class constructor and use a constant number instead in that base constructor so that one is used for every derived class too. If the argument needs to differ per derived class though, then there is no other way.

Comment: Sounds like a case of Bad Inheritance. Does the derived class really meet the is-a requirement of polymorphism? If the base class really needs that parameter, how can the child classes ignore it?

Comment: Yeah, the derived class is specific kind of graph, while the super class is generic graph. In my case, any graph needs to receive data to be rendered as an argument. So either C++ must figure it out (which is why I'm asking) or I have to write it manually for every graph type.

Comment: Could you also post a realistic error? The one in your example doesn't match the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the derived classes have to pass some value to the base class. It will be easy for the derived classes to have a default constructor in the base class that is in the `protected` section. You can initialize the member data of the base class that makes sense for the derived classes.

```
class SuperClass {
  public:
    SuperClass(const int parameter);
  protected:
    SuperClass() : SuperClass(10) {} // Delegate to the other constructor.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you have a certain set of children, all of which need the `SuperClass` constructor to be called with the same default argument, all you need to do is to introduce an intermediary with no-argument constructor, which would call the `SuperClass::SuperClass` with the magic number.

Answer (score 0):

Make the parameter defaulted.

```
class SuperClass {
public:
    SuperClass(const int parameter = DEFAULT);
}
```

You can then chose to include the constructor in your initialize list, or use the default.

Default value:

```
class NoParameterChildDefault : public SuperClass
{
public:
   NoParameterChildDefault() : someText("Hello") { ... } // uses value DEFAULT.
};
```

Explicit Value:

```
class NoParameterChildExplicit : public SuperClass
{
public:
  NoParameterChildExplicit() : SuperClass(5), someText("Hello") { ... } // uses value '5'.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna change your default child constructor:

```
class NoParametersInConstructorClass : public SuperClass {
public:
    NoParametersInConstructorClass(int n =0) : SuperClass(n)someText("Hello") {};
 private:
    std::string someText
}
```

This way both `NoParametersInConstructorClass variable(66);` and `NoParametersInConstructorClass variable;` will work.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your edited question:
You can use the `using` keyword to make the derived class use the base class constructor:

```
class NoParametersInConstructorClass : public SuperClass {
public:
    using SuperClass::SuperClass;
    NoParametersInConstructorClass() : someText("Hello") {};
private:
    std::string someText
}
```

You have to somehow define a constructor for the derived class. You can't just call the base class constructor for the derived class without the `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you can't (or you won't) modify the base class to add a default constructor, you have to call the constructor of the base class in its valid form (with argument) in initialization list of every derived class (like [here](http://rextester.com/KFS99061))